# How to set large collection to entity with best performance by JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Let's say if there is a `Owner` class and an `Item` class, they are in a `@ManyToMany` relation through an association table.

```
public class Owner{
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "OWNERITEM", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName="USERID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEMID", referencedColumnName="ITEMID")
    )
    private List<Item> items= new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

Assume there are other fields/mapping relations under `Item` class, and now if there is case require to add all items(say 2000 or 10000 items) to a specific `Owner` object, then the code must be

```
// we have to to question the performance here...
Owner owner = someService.getOwner(Parameters... someParameters);
List<Item> all_items = itemService.findAll();
owner.setItems(all_items);
```

See above process, it is not very efficient, especially when `Item` class has(even lazy fetch) relations to other class, then there will be many, many unnecessary queries to pull those data into 10 thousands `Item` objects. But it is just the `Item.id` that we need to insert into `Owner-Item` relations to map all items to the user.

What I can think of is to register `Item itemId` instead of `Item object` into Owner class, but that seems make the coding a lot more complicated as we have to develop method to pull all item information.

Is there any better alternative to guarantee a good performance?

Answer (score 0):

Use modifying repository query, like this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

for example:

```
@Query("update Item i set i.owner = ?1")
```